# How to access ngrx entity selectors in angular lazy-loading module?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-entity

I'm trying to implement an application using NGRX state management library.I was able to create action and reducers to push data to lazy-loaded state. But I'm struggling to implement selectors to get data to components. This is what I have done so far

**reducer/job-file.reducer.ts** here I'm using ngrx entity plugin

```
import {Action, createReducer, on} from '@ngrx/store';

import * as JobFileActions from '../actions';
import {JobFile} from '../../models/job-file.model';
import {createEntityAdapter, EntityAdapter, EntityState} from '@ngrx/entity';

export const jobFIleFeatureKey = 'jobFile';

export const adapter: EntityAdapter<JobFile> = createEntityAdapter<JobFile>({
  selectId: (jobFile: JobFile) => jobFile.jobRefId
});

export interface State extends EntityState<JobFile> {
  selectedJobRefId: string;
}

export const initialState: State = adapter.getInitialState({
  selectedJobRefId: null,
});

export const reducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(JobFileActions.AddJobFile as any, (state: State, action: {jobFile: JobFile}) => {
    return adapter.addOne(action.jobFile, state);
  })
);

export const selectedJobRefId = (state: State) => state.selectedJobRefId;
```

**reducer/index.ts**

```
import {ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromJobFile from './job-file.reducer';

export const scheduleFeatureKey = 'schedule';

export interface ScheduleState {
  [fromJobFile.jobFIleFeatureKey]: fromJobFile.State;
}

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<ScheduleState> = {
  [fromJobFile.jobFIleFeatureKey]: fromJobFile.reducer
};
```

**schedule.module.ts**

```
import * as fromSchedule from './store/reducers';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ScheduleComponent, ContainerDetailsComponent, AssignScheduleComponent, LegComponent, ResourceOverviewPanelComponent,
    ResourceNavigationComponent],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
    ScheduleRoutingModule,
    StoreModule.forFeature('schedule', fromSchedule.reducers)
  ]
})
```

**selectors.ts** this is the place I'm struggling right now

```
import { adapter as jobFileAdaptor } from '../reducers/job-file.reducer';
import {createFeatureSelector, createSelector} from '@ngrx/store';
import { ScheduleState } from '../reducers';

export const selectJobFileState = createFeatureSelector<ScheduleState>('jobList');

export const a = createSelector(selectJobFileState, jobFileAdaptor.getSelectors().selectAll);
export const {
  selectIds: selectAllJobIds,
  selectAll: selectAllJobFiles,
  selectEntities: selectAllJobEntities,
  selectTotal: selectTotalJobs
}  = jobFileAdaptor.getSelectors();
```

I'm getting below error. Does anyone know how to write these selectors
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the issue is the type of `selectJobFileState`, in that `ScheduleState` is not an implementation of `EntityState`.  Instead it contains a key with an EnitityState as its value.

```js
// In your reducers index.ts
export { State as JobFileEntityState } from './job-file.reducer';

// In selectors.ts
import { JobFileEntityState } from '../reducers';

export const selectJobFileState = createFeatureSelector<JobFileEntityState>('jobList');
```

Side note: If you are going to specify the feature selector key as a string literal in `selectors.ts`, why bother using a variable elsewhere.  Be consistent.  You should probably import the jobList feature key variable and use that instead of the string.